# Angular providers and providedIn causing circular dependancy

Tags: angular

I am new to angular, so I have a pretty basic question for you guys.

I started a project a couple of months ago and when I created a service, I added it to the **providers** array in my module.
Something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { MatchService } from '../../core/services/match.service';
import { Answer } from '../../core/models/answer';
import { Product } from '../../core/models/product';

@Injectable()
export class ScenarioMatchService {

  constructor(
    private matchService: MatchService
  ) { }

  find(product: Product, answers: Answer[]): string[] {
    var descriptions: string[] = [];

    answers.forEach(answer => {
      var formulas = answer.formulas;
      var match = this.matchService.matchProductUsingFormulas(product, formulas);
      if (match)
        descriptions.push(answer.text);
    })

    return descriptions;
  }
}
```

And in my module, I would have something like `providers: [ScenarioMatchService]`. This seemed to be working fine.
I noticed the other day I am getting a new decoration when creating services:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
```

So I have read this articule:
https://angular.io/guide/providers

Now, I have a `CoreModule` where my singleton services live. So I thought it was a good idea to update all my services that reside in that folder to this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: CoreModule
})
```

But now I am getting a warning from angular:

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src\app\core\animations\animations.component.ts -> src\app\core\services\animation.service.ts -> src\app\core\core.module.ts -> src\app\core\animations\animations.component.ts

What am I doing wrong to cause this?

Comment: Have you provided it in `AppModule` or `CoreModule`? Either ways you will have to remove it from the module file because `@Injectable({
  providedIn: CoreModule
})` does the same thing. Just import `CoreModule` in `AppModule`

Comment: This is just a warning, which most of the time is related to your imports, you probably import a class from file A into file B and a class from file B into file A.

Comment: i am trying to keep it all separate, so no I dont have anything provided in app module or core module. I just have the decorators in the "core" services.

Comment: I mean for example, it states that a component depends on a service (it's injected), which depends on a module (using the decorator) which then declares the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10170

The article above solved my issue.
I replaced all the `@Injectable({ providedIn: CoreModule })` with @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) and for any services that I want to be lazy loaded are provided using the module **providers** array (i.e. the old way)

Answer (score 0):

Error message clearly says there is circular dependency in your configuration.

Remove all those services from `core.module.ts` `providers` which you have configured with

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: CoreModule
})
```